# Trying to Make an Average Finder, Not Using ReadLine(), using Only Console

Tags: java, console, console-application, command-line-arguments, average

New to Java, basically started yesterday.

Okay, so here's the thing.

I'm trying to make an 'averager', if you wanna call it that, **that accepts a random amount of numbers. I shouldn't have to define it in the program, it has to be arbitrary.** I have to make it work on Console.

But I can't use Console.ReadLine() or Scanner or any of that. I have to input the data through the Console itself. So, when I call it, I'd type into the Console:

```
java AveragerConsole 1 4 82.4
```

which calls the program and gives the three arguments: 1, 4 and 82.4

I think that the problem I'm having is, I can't seem to tell it this:

*If the next field in the array is empty, calculate the average* (check Line 14 in code)

My code's below:

```
public class AveragerConsole
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    boolean stop = false;
    int n = 0;
    double x;
    double total = 0;
    while (stop == false)
    {
        if (args[n] == "")  //Line 14
        {
            double average = total / (n-1);
            System.out.println("Average is equal to: "+average);
            stop = true;
        }
        else
        {
            x = Double.parseDouble(args[n]);
            total = total + x;
            n = n + 1;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at AveragerConsole.main(AveragerConsole.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(String number : args) {
  // do something with one argument, your else branch mostly
}
```

Also, you don't need n, you already have the number of arguments, it's the args length.
This is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try that now and let you know if I figured it out :)

Comment: No problem. Have fun with Java. :)

Answer (score 1):

You gave 3 inputs and array start couting from 0. The array `args` as per your input is as follows.

```
args[0] = 1
args[1] = 4
args[2] = 82.4
```

and

```
args[3] = // Index out of bound
```

Better implementation would be like follows

```
double sum = 0.0;

// No fault tolerant checking implemented
for(String value: args)
   sum += Double.parseDouble(value);

double average = sum/args.length;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) Edited my code to clarify:  the program has to accept a random amount of numbers through console. I shouldn't have to define it in the program, it has to be arbitrary

Comment: I was just giving an example as per your exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3`

Comment: Yup, saw @SilviuBurcea's `for` loop suggestion. Brilliant, helped a lot! :) Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

For String value comparisons, you must use the `equals()` method.

```
if ("".equals(args[n]))
```

And next, the max valid index in an array is always `array.length - 1`. If you try to access the `array.length` index, it'll give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You've got this probably because your `if` did not evaluate properly, as you used `==` for String value comparison.

On a side note, I really doubt if this `if` condition of yours is ever gonna be evaluated, unless you manually enter a blank string after inputting all the numbers.

Change the condition in your while to this and your program seems to be working all fine for `n` numbers. (*@SilviuBurcea*'s solution seems to be the best since you don't need to keep track of the `n` yourself)

```
while (n < args.length)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Could you please explain? I'm guessing I have to use that method to compare args[n] and the blank field? Is my code, in general, correct, not regarding line 14?

Comment: Not quite! Your `while` isn't that great because I really doubt that you'll get a blank string to check with!

Comment: You're right, the `while` wasn't a good idea. Changed it to a for loop as suggested above by @SilviuBurcea and @TheKojuEffect. Thanks to all of you!